# Create table and alter table dynamically in scala slick

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

How to create table and alter table dynamically in scala slick?
Is the way just only play SQL query?

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean the Slick table objects or the schema in the database? In case of the former, you can call `.column` on your table object any time to request a column dynamcally. In case of the latter, Slick allows to create new schemas. For manipulation existing schemas use SQL or play evolutions. More info here: [Play!: Does Slick's DDL replace Evolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404569)