# Create table from slick table definition

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

In PlaySlick sample there is file with sample data access object.

https://github.com/playframework/play-slick/blob/master/samples/basic/app/dao/CatDAO.scala

and table definition:

```
  private class CatsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Cat](tag, "CAT") {

    def name = column[String]("NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
    def color = column[String]("COLOR")

    def * = (name, color) <> (Cat.tupled, Cat.unapply)
  }
```

Is it possible to generate a new table using this definition without using play evolutions? If not, why?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, it is not possible using only slick table definitions.
From slick documentation:

> Slick itself does not have out-of-the-box support for database
>   migrations, but there are some third-party tools that work well with
>   Slick.

But they point out some alternatives [here](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.0-M1/migrations.html).

From some person that work at the slick team:

> Both Slick and the Slick DDL Plugin can only generate code to create
>   or delete your schema, not to evolve it. So you still need Play
>   evolutions or something similar to modify an existing schema along the
>   way.

Checkout the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404569/play-does-slicks-ddl-replace-evolutions/21428713#21428713).