# Can slick automatically create tables in the database (generate SQL and execute) from the models?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-codegen

I've understood that slick-codegen can generate scala classes from the database tables. Can we do the opposite, creating tables if they don't exist in the database from the models?

Comment: I believe not directly, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46382360/create-table-from-slick-table-definition

Comment: Thanks @Ossip. 
The latest version of play at this point says the DDL plugin is removed.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlaySlickMigrationGuide#DDL-support-was-removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create tables in Slick from a model: it's not related to the codegen tool, though.

When you define a model in Slick, you can use the `.schema` method to generate the database schema commands. There are examples of this in [The Slick Manual](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.1/schemas.html#data-definition-language):

```
 // Assuming we have coffees and suppliers queries, we combine the schemas:
 val schema = coffees.schema ++ suppliers.schema


 // Now we can run a variety of commands to CREATE TABLE etc:
 db.run(DBIO.seq(
   schema.create,
   schema.createIfNotExists,
   schema.drop,
   schema.dropIfExists
))
```

However, that's not automatic: you'd need to write something in your start-up code to decide to run the DDL commands or not.

Comment: I would add that slick's ability to create tables should not be used as any kind of database migration framework.